# How transform a pointer function to a class function? c++

Tags: c++, class, linked-list

I've got this delete function:

```
Node* deleteNode(Node *head, Node *node)
{
    if (head != 0)
    {
        if (head == node)
            head = head->next;
        else
            head->next = deleteNode(head->next, node);
    }
    return head;
}
```

But to make it more clear (because the rest of the functions of my program is in a class) I want to make it as something like:

```
void List::deleteNode()
{
    //the code comes here
}
```

(I want to delete from the beginning of the single linked list and don't want to use libraries.)

Comment: Your question isn't very clear - are you implementing your own List class? If so, just keep a pointer to the first node as a member in your class. You'll always have to pass in at least one argument  though (the node you'd like to delete).

Comment: He wrote "I want to delete from the beginning" so no argument is needed, though the function name is misleading.

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
void List::deleteNode()
{
    /* I suppose you have Node *head in your List class */
    if(head == NULL)
        return;

    Node * temp = head;
    head = head -> next;

    delete temp;
}
```

I think that "deleteHead" is a better name for this function.

Comment: Oh thanks! And what if I want to delete the head and the following node? I think then I need arguments.

Comment: You can just delete head twice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going about this the wrong way, you should first think about what the class looks and feels like and then about what's going in there. When I'm considering putting code into a class, in particular code that handles something like your list, I first make a mental list of operations (append, erase, find?, index?) that the class needs to support. Then, I start thinking about the  interface that I want the class to have. Then, putting the code into the class is usually a small step, as most of it is already decided by the two steps before.

Looking at your code, I see that the return value is only used to reset the previous element's `next` pointer after the recursive call. Therefore, you could split the function in one for users of the list and one that is used internally only. This is an important point, because it means that the interface of the class only has to show to the outside ("public") the one for users of the class. What it does internally is its own business. This allows you to change this from recursion to iteration (which would be more efficient), without disturbing users of the class.

Now, in your case, you have a list that you want to put into a class. You can delete elements from the list, where you specify the elements by their address. This doesn't destroy the elements but leaves that to the caller (raw pointers always ask the ownership question, but that is a different issue). Anything else is to me unknown yet, like e.g. how to fill the list or how to allocate a node. This gives me this use case with the erase operation:

```
List l;
... // fill l
Node* n = ... // some node
l.erase(n);
delete n;
```

For the list type, this then looks like this:

```
struct List
{
    void erase(Node* n)
    {
        m_head = doErase(m_head, n);
    }
private:
    static Node* doErase(Node* head, Node* node)
    {
        ... // your function here
    }

    Node* m_head;
};
```

Note that there are still several things missing, in particular you want to make your class non-copyable and you have to decide what to do when the node is null (e.g. `assert(n);` in `erase()`) or not in the list (`throw invalid_argument("node not element of list");` in `do_erase()`). However, I hope that this should get you started.